# Determine the number of $30$-digit telephone numbers consisting of the digits $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ such that the number $3$'s are odd .

Tags: combinatorics

Determine the number of $30$-digit telephone numbers consisting of the digits $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ such that the number a) $3$'s are odd b) the total number of $3$’s and $5$’s is even.

The answer for a) is $\frac{1}{2}(5^{30}-3^{30})$. But I got the answer $\sum_{k=0}^{14}C(30,2k+1)4^{(30-(2k+1))}$. For example if there are $5$ $3$'s they can be distributed in $C(30,5)$ ways and then there are $25$ spots left which can be filled in $4^{25}$. So the number of sequences with $5$ $3$'s is $C(30,5)* 4^{25}$.

The answer for b) is $\frac{1}{2}(5^{30}+1)$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but unsimplified; it is much simpler to evaluate $\frac12(5^{30}-3^{30})$ than to evaluate a summation with $15$ terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Classic Approach**

A classic trick in combinatorics is using the following expression:

$$
\left(x+1\right)^{2n}-\left(x-1\right)^{2n}=
2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\cdot x^{2n-(2k+1)}
$$

When you expand the two terms on the left hand side, the even terms $x^{2m}$ cancel out while the odd terms $x^{2m+1}$ adds up. Therefore we have:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\cdot x^{2n-(2k+1)}=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(x+1\right)^{2n}-\left(x-1\right)^{2n}\right]
$$

**Your Answer**

In your answer, we have $n=15$ and $x=4$:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{14}\binom{30}{2k+1}\cdot 4^{2n-(2k+1)}=
\frac{1}{2}\left[5^{30}-3^{30}\right]
$$

**Generalization**

For question b, you probably end up with the following answer:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{30}{2k}\cdot 2^{2k}\cdot 3^{2n-2k}
$$

for which you can use a more generalized form of the classic expression above:

$$
\left(x+y\right)^{2n}+\left(x-y\right)^{2n}
=
2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\cdot x^{2k}\cdot y^{2n-2k}
$$

I leave the rest for you

**Generalization of The Generalization**

You may want to look into "roots of unity" if you are not familiar with it. The $m$-th roots of unity is the roots of the following polynomial:

$$
1 + x + x^{2} + ... + x^{m-1} = 0
$$

If you multiple the equation above with $(1-x)$, you get $x^{m}=1$, hence the name "roots of unity". So for example, the third roots of unity satisfy the followings:

$$
1 + x + x^{2} = 0 \phantom{x}\text{and}\phantom{x} x^{3} = 1
$$

We can use this to derive some tricks:

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} \left(p+qx^{r}\right)^{n}
=
m\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor}
\binom{n}{mk}p^{n-mk}q^{mk}
$$

I leave the proving to you. In your original question, we use the second roots of unity $1+x=0\iff x=-1$ and $m=2$:

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{1}\left(p+q(-1)^{r}\right)^{n}
=
2\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}p^{2n-2k}q^{2k}
$$

Comment: Ooh, very nice trick! ❤️ Do you know if there's a trick, maybe even including complex numbers, which gives you the sum of every third term or some such generalization?

Comment: @SuhailSherif I added more generalization using the roots of unity. If you want the sum of every third terms, use the third roots of unity. Roots of unity are complex numbers (except the second one), so yes your intuition is correct that it involves a complex number

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is completely correct, and therefore so is your answer. To get the other answer, if it was given to you you can verify it by induction on the length of the phone number. If you had to come up with it in your own, you could do so by finding a recursive formula for the length of the phone number and solving that. You can ask for any clarifications or if there was something else you were looking for from this post.